# How to Remove the IP canalization using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ip, canonicalization

Recently I have gone through my website with some SEO tools and they suggest that I remove my IP canalization using .htaccess file, but I don't know how to remove this using .htaccess file code.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only domain that you host from your document root, then you can try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.neotericuk\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.neotericuk.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If there are other hosts that are also being hosted from the same document root, then you can match specifically for the IP address:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^neotericuk\.co\.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.neotericuk.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

where **1.2.3.4** is your server's IP address.